# Is $ |iz| = |z|$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z=x+iy$ where $i$ is imaginary.  Define $|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
What is $|iz|$

My textbook claims that $|z|=|iz|$ but I am unable to prove it.

My attempt a proof is below

$i(x+iy) = ix -y$

$(ix)^2 + y^2 = y^2 -x^2$

so they are not equal

Comment: If $z = x + iy$, then $iz = -y + ix$.  Then $|iz| = \sqrt{(-y)^2 + x^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = |z|$.

Comment: By your logic, you would have had $x^2+(iy)^2 = x^2-y^2$ in the case of $z=x+iy$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider that$$|iz|=|i||z|=|z|$$

Answer (score 2):

NO computation required: simply don't forget the modulus of a complex number is a *multiplicative* function, i.e. $|zz'|=|z|\,|z'|$, and that $|i|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $z\bar{z}=(x+iy)(x-iy)=x^2+y^2=|z|^2$, this implies $|iz|^2=(iz)(\bar{iz})=iz(-i\bar{z})=|z|^2$. But there's more, as a matter of fact

$$ |z_1z_2|^2=z_1\bar{z_1}z_2\bar{z_2}=|z_1|^2|z_2|^2$$

then it is trivial that $|iz|=|i||z|=|z|$